Does the anti-Christ in Islam have one or two eyes?
I have been studying the Quran about what prophet Muhammed wrote concerning the physical attributes of the anti-Christ. Does the Quran actually confirm that he will have two eyes but one eye will be blinded? or does it actually say that this person will only have one eye on the head? This is because this prophecy was written more than 1400 years ago but there seems to be some hidden secret in Hollywood concerning blinding the right eye as most celebrities block or blind the right eye.
Anas Ibn Malik narrated that Muhammed said:

"There is never a prophet who has not warned the Ummah of that one-eyed liar; behold he is one-eyed and your Lord is not one-eyed.[19] Dajjal is blind of one eye[20] On his forehead are the letters k. f. r. (Kafir)[19] between the eyes of the Dajjal[21] which every Muslim would be able to read."

So is it true that he will be one eyed technically or he wil have both eyes but one will be made blind?


His one eye will be blind.
حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، حَدَّثَنَا جُوَيْرِيَةُ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، قَالَ ذُكِرَ الدَّجَّالُ عِنْدَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لاَ يَخْفَى عَلَيْكُمْ، إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَيْسَ بِأَعْوَرَ ـ وَأَشَارَ بِيَدِهِ إِلَى عَيْنِهِ ـ وَإِنَّ الْمَسِيحَ الدَّجَّالَ أَعْوَرُ الْعَيْنِ الْيُمْنَى كَأَنَّ عَيْنَهُ عِنَبَةٌ طَافِيَةٌ ‏"‏‏.‏
Narrated `Abdullah: Ad-Dajjal was mentioned in the presence of the Prophet. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah is not hidden from you; He is not one-eyed," and pointed with his hand towards his eye, adding, "While Al-Masih Ad- Dajjal is blind in the right eye and his eye looks like a protruding grape."
Sahih al-Bukhari 7407
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7407

I can't believe that Islam predicted this more than 1400 years ago
